# Why is there an upper limit on the premium of an ATM (!) call swaption in the Black76 model?

Tags: implied-volatility, interest-rate-swap, swaption, black76

Trying to imply Black76 (where the forward swap rate is log-normal) volatilities as Bloomberg does in their VCUB screen we see holes at two regions:

- at short maturities due to negative rates which can not be captured in a log-normal model - that is clear
- and also at high maturities - which is suprising for me.

The documentation says that in the Black76 model there is an upper bound for ATM-call prices on swap-rates. If the premium is higher, then one can not imply the volatility. But how can there be an upper bound?

EDIT: Is the upper bound just the discounted rate?
If we recall B76 
$$
C= \exp(-r T)[F N(d_1) - K N(d_2)],
$$
then ATM means $F=K$ and thus
$$
C= \exp(-r T)F [N(d_1) - N(d_2)],
$$
which is
$$
\exp(-r T)F [N(\sigma \sqrt{T}/2) - N(-\sigma \sqrt{T}/2)],
$$
and using symmetry we arrive at
$$
\exp(-r T)F [1-2N(-\sigma \sqrt{T}/2)] \le \exp(-r T)F,
$$
which would be a rather high bound ....

Comment: Writing down the equations I start to get a feeling that for ATM there might exist a bound ...

Comment: That appears fine with me. Note that $F$ is the forward swap rate, which can not be too large.

Comment: Yes .. maybe that's all. It was not clear to me until today when I saw that this is the reason why BB does not deliver any implie vola (B76) for long maturities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the BS model there is the upper bound of the stock price, which can be proven by the fact the stock price bounds the call option pay-off. Here we are seeing a similar effect: the discounted rate corresponds to the stock price.